# Retrieve message attribute name from Amazon SQS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-sqs

I am trying to get the user data by entering into a form, then send and store user data into the Amazon SQS. The details are visible in the Amazon SQS along with the message attribute name. There is a listener that I have implemented to fetch the data from Amazon SQS queue and store it into the MS-SQL database.

The screenshot below shows the message attribute name in Amazon SQS:

[image]

**Issue:** When I try to fetch the data from Amazon SQS using the listener, I am getting the user data but unable to get/fetch the "message attribute name". The following piece of code I have added in my listener to get the message attribute name is:

```
// Created an object of ReceiveMessageRequest class to pass values to all the parameters.
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
receiveMessageRequest.QueueUrl = urlSQS;
receiveMessageRequest.MaxNumberOfMessages = 10;
List<string> AttributesList = new List<string>();
AttributesList.Add("ContactsQueue");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You attribute is named `Class`, but you're requesting attribute named `ContactsQueue`. That's all you need:

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest()
{
    QueueUrl = urlSQS,
    MaxNumberOfMessages = 10,
    MessageAttributeNames = new List<string>() {"Class"}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest.withMessageAttributeNames("attributeTest")).getMessages();
```